# Performance reactive forms

Tags: angular

My application has grown and I'm having performance issue when objects are too big and nested.

Analyzing my code, today when I need to change some value inside the component via typescript, I use Spread.

**Example:**
Let's assume I have an object called currentdata.

```
currentdata: {
    user: {
       name: "glauber"
     }
}
```

Let's say I need to change the username value, today I do it as follows.

```
this.currentData = {
     ...(this.currentData || {}),
    user: {
        ...(this.currentdata?.user || {}),
       name: 'Jonas'
    }
}
```

Instead of using the reactive form mechanisms, example.

```
this.form.get().patchvalue()
```

I would like to know if this approach that I do, can generate more slowness, excessive firing of events.

Comment: How do you render the subarray? , is it in the single-component or divided into multiple components, with subobjects are being handled in child components

Comment: Since you are not using reactive form API, you are not firing any events at all